# перенос слов по дефису

Tags: html, css

Столкнулся с непонятной мне проблемой в css. Хром переносит слова по дефису. Т.е. фраза: "Проект дома я-455-555", если не влезает в ширину переносит не словом целиком, а может взять и отрезать именно по дефису: "Проект дома я-455-(перенос)555"
[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Никакие `white-space`, типа `pre-wrap`, `pre-line` не работают.

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с этой проблемой?

Answer (score 4):

Как вариант использовать неразрывный дефис

http://jsfiddle.net/nghtpxwc/

```
<p>Проект дома я&#8209;455&#8209;555</p>
```

```css
p { 
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    width: 150px;
    min-height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;  
    padding: 10px;
}
```

или так http://jsfiddle.net/jmwqngjc/

Comment: Как я писал pre-wrap не работает. Все равно переносит именно по дефису. Неразрывный дефис просто так не получится вставить, ибо название проекта вбивается через админку в обычное текстовое поле. Заставить девочку-контентщицу вставлять вместо дефисов такие "крокозябры" не вариант. Остается JS-скриптом? Но это жестоко будет. Позиций-то почти под 1000. На клиенте машина будет висеть нещадно. Странно, что такая вещь творится именно в Хроме. В Лисе всё отлично - перенос слова целиком.

Comment: а второй вариант http://jsfiddle.net/jmwqngjc/?

Comment: неужели это такая большая проблема - заставить исполнителя вместо дефиса вставлять из буфера обмена &#8209; ?.. гнал бы взашей таких "девочек-контентщиц"...

Answer (score 3):

Если это частный случай, то можно посмотреть в сторону тега `nobr`

Answer (score 2):

Используйте преобразование дефиса при сохранении в БД.

Код для php (между вторыми кавычками стоит неразрывный дефис):

```
$content = str_replace('-', '‑', $content);
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете убрать перенос совсем. Для этого используйте следующие стили:

```
p{
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```